# How to use workspace from local machine on Jenkins instance

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have workspace in my local, I want to use it as workspace in jenkins instance. How do I mention that path location which is present in local? How do I make all the execution to run locally and use Jenkins just to trigger the jobs?

Comment: Is the machine you're talking about already connected to Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Connect your machine as an agent to Jenkins. Here is a good [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows). And in `Remote root directory` specify your workspace.